# Chrome Postman does not show Cookies button

Tags: cookies, postman

I've been using Postman for ages, and it is great.  I am using Windows 10, and Postman is started from a link.

I have to do a bit of mucking around with Cookies now, but I cannot get the Cookies button, near send, to be visible.  I have installed Interceptor and turned it on in the app, rebooted etc, but still nothing.

As a workaround I believe I can manually get or set cookies, but I am not sure how to do this.  I am looking to have complete control of the cookie, ie expiration time and protocol etc.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Postman Chrome app does not have a Cookies button. Check out the [documentation](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/cookies), where it states that only the native apps have the modal. Interceptor is the only way to go. Another solution would be to install the Windows app and export/sync your data.

Check out [this page](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/launching_postman/installation_and_updates) as well, to see all the differences between native and Chrome apps.

Comment: Very helpful!  It would have been brilliant to see this page (https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/cookies) have some kind of message like "You need the native app for the cookie feature".  Thanks, Ray, for your guidance.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Postman
2. requester.json && setting.json remove
3. reinstall postman
4. install postman.

Your problem is solved.

Comment: i have found in this location C:\Users\{User}\AppData\Roaming\Postman and it is working